# $2s\rightarrow 1s$ transition in hydrogen

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics

I would like to understand how the parity-violated interaction between electron and proton can provide the photon with circular polarization in the $2s\rightarrow 1s$ transition with *single* photon emission. As I understand, this interaction plays the crucial role. I only have found [this](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221B-S01/finalsol.pdf) problem and have read the [paper](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1940ApJ....91..215B) by Breit & Teller, where the authors discuss metastability of $2s$ state.

I am looking for any references, books, etc which can be helpful for my problem.

Comment: I do not understand what you meant by "parity-violated interaction between electron and proton". Where is it mentioned in the problem set you have linked? It just shows that single photon emission can happen by magnetic dipole transition but it's much slower than two-photon electric dipole transition.

Comment: Interesting case. I found this paper but it is behind a paywall : https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134%2FS0030400X0804005X

Comment: @IamAStudent, I have corrected the question, thank you

Comment: "....photon with non-zero helicity" all photons have non-zero helicity as there can be only two values of $\pm1$. I am suspecting that your question really boils down to how a magnetic dipole transition works.

Comment: @IamAStudent , it was my fault. Now I have edited the question. In M1 transition the photon has not circular polarization.

Comment: On the contrary. M1 transition can have circular polarizations (e.g. |2,-2> to |1,-1> hyperfine transition in rubidium atoms).

Comment: @IamAStudent I mean that the specific 1M $2s\rightarrow 1s$ in hydrogen has no circular polarization, isn't it?

Comment: "how the parity-violated interaction between electron and proton can provide the photon with circular polarization in the $2s\rightarrow 1s$ transition with *single* photon emission" - what makes you so sure that it is involved? It's definitely not present in either of the sources you've cited, from what I can tell. The single-photon contribution to that transition (the M1 component, which represents a minuscule part of the transition strength) is already capable of producing nonzero helicities. Why do you think that parity violations are required?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty , of course, I do not understand the M1 $2s\rightarrow 1s$ totally. My question is related to my problem and my supervisor said that in M1 transition photon has no circular polarization.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty , I have found [this book](https://books.google.ru/books?id=GW6pclAk-JcC&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=circular+polarization+of+photon+parity+violation+hydrogen+2s+1s&source=bl&ots=AUOvbTb8C0&sig=ACfU3U3Zv_bdfYMAu-6d4WW2NHw_MuHiPg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZjpKGubHhAhWrk4sKHYFqBDMQ6AEwA3oECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=circular%20polarization%20of%20photon%20parity%20violation%20hydrogen%202s%201s&f=false), where there is a few relevent information (see 1.14 & 1.13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't particularly clear to me what you mean by

> I would like to understand how the parity-violated interaction between electron and proton can provide the photon with circular polarization in the $2s\rightarrow 1s$ transition with single photon emission.

and particularly what you really mean by "understand how ...".

- The fact that the symmetries of this transition do allow for a nontrivial difference in the emission rates to different helicities is reasonably well explained in Problem 3 of one document you've linked to (['Final Solutions'](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221B-S01/finalsol.pdf), to the 221B course at Berkeley, 2001, by Hitoshi Murayama).
- The specific meaning of 'circular polarization' is explained fairly well in footnote 18, p. 63, problem 1.14, of the book you've linked to, [*Atomic Physics: An Exploration Through Problems and Solutions*](https://books.google.ru/books?id=GW6pclAk-JcC&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=circular+polarization+of+photon+parity+violation+hydrogen+2s+1s&source=bl&ots=AUOvbTb8C0&sig=ACfU3U3Zv_bdfYMAu-6d4WW2NHw_MuHiPg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZjpKGubHhAhWrk4sKHYFqBDMQ6AEwA3oECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=circular%20polarization%20of%20photon%20parity%20violation%20hydrogen%202s%201s&f=false) (D. Budker, D. F. Kimball and David P. DeMille, Oxford University Press, 2004).

In short, you define a quantization axis (by convention, the $z$ axis), you prepare $2S_{1/2}$ atoms in definite-$\hat{S}_z$ states, and you put detectors at the positive and negative $z$ axis, which are able to detect the helicity of the produced photons, and which are insensitive to the two-photon radiation at half the $2S_{1/2}$-$1S_{1/2}$ energy spacing. Then preparing the $m_s=+1/2$ state will produce a right-circular photon ($S_z=1$) and preparing the $m_s=-1/2$ state will produce a right-circular photon ($S_z=-1$). Within standard QED, both of these channels *do* come out with circular polarizations (despite your claims to the contrary in comments), but they do so at equal rates. If you include parity-violating weak interactions, then there will be a nonzero difference in the emission rates for the two, probably at the "large" level of one part in $10^4$. (If I understand the literature below correctly, that is.)

If you want to go beyond that, then there is just an enormous sliding scale of difficulty in terms of how technical you want to get, with no clear cutoff point for what constitutes "understanding" $-$ which is in any case a personal, subjective descriptor.

---

Still, since you've tagged this as resource-recommendations, here is one way into that rabbit hole:

- [Searching for `"1s-2s" M1 hydrogen parity` on Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%221s-2s%22+M1+hydrogen+parity&btnG=)
- The first paper from that list, 'Parity Nonconservation in Relativistic Hydrogenic Ions', M. Zolotorev and D. Budker, [*Phys. Rev. Lett.* **78**, 4717 (1997)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.78.4717), leading in particular to its references 1 and 2, which deal with hydrogenic ions,
- '$2S_{1/2}\to1S_{1/2}+\text{one-photon}$ decay of muonic atoms and parity-violating neutral-current interactions', G. Feinberg and M. Y. Chen, [*Phys. Rev. D* **10**, 190 (1974)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.10.190) and
- 'Analysis of weak neutral currents in hydrogenic ions', R. W. Dunford and R. R. Lewis, [*Phys. Rev. A* **23**, 10 (1981)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.23.10), and particularly its reference 11, the two papers
- 'Weak neutral currents in atoms and μ-mesic atons', A. N. Moskalev, *Zh. Eksp. Teor. Fiz. Pis'Ma Red.* **19**, 229 (1974); [*JETP Lett.* **19**, 141 (1974)](http://www.jetpletters.ac.ru/ps/1776/article_27042.shtml); and
- 'Some parity-nonconservation effects in emission by hydrogenlike atoms', Ya. I. Azimov et al., *Zh. Eksp. Teor. Fiz.* **67**, 17 (1974); [*Sov. Phys. JETP* **40**, 8 (1975)](http://www.jetp.ac.ru/cgi-bin/e/index/e/40/1/p8?a=list).

That last paper is probably where all the real action is - but maybe there are other rabbit-hole branches coming from other reference follow-ups, so do look around.

Still, given how unclear the question is about what exactly it is you want to know, I don't really see how digging into any of these specific resources with a deeper analysis would make sense. (And also: if you don't find anything in this list accessible, then I would suggest that it's too ambitious of a target for you at this stage.)

---

In any case, though, I have to ask: why are you so interested in this? As the problem set you've linked to lays out very clearly, the two-photon decay mechanism dominates the M1 single-photon channel by a factor of $\alpha^6\approx 1.5 \times 10^{-13}$, or, in other words, "this channel just doesn't happen in real life": you need to prepare $10^{13}$ metastable atoms for one of them to decay via the M1 route, and you need to repeat this $10^4$ times to get any signal at all.

This is not to say that the channel isn't interesting, but that challenge does mean that if you want to use the $2s$-$1s$ transition to test this type of mechanism, your best bet is to look at higher hydrogenic ions or similar systems $-$ as the literature above demonstrates.

And, moreover, this is also why the current work on using precision spectroscopy to test CPT-related effects (which is quite substantial $-$ for a decent recent review on work with hydrogenic systems see e.g. 'Lorentz and CPT tests with hydrogen, antihydrogen, and related systems', V. Alan Kostelecký and Arnaldo J. Vargas, [*Phys. Rev. D* **92**, 056002 (2015)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.92.056002)) does not use this system.

Comment: Weak neutral currents provide the circular polarization which can be estimated as $P=FA(E_1)/A(M_1)$, where $A(E_1)$ is the amplitude of $2p_{1/2}\rightarrow 1s_{1/2}$ and $A(M_1)$ is the amplitude for magnetic dipole transition, $F$ is mixing between $2p_{1/2}$ and $2s_{1/2}$ states due to parity violating interaction. Your answers was really helpful and comprehensive. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

There are two parity-even operators that contribute to the $2s\to 1s$ transition: $(\vec{p}\cdot \vec{A})^2$ and $\sigma\cdot \vec{B}$. The first obviously contains two photons but the second is just a spin flip. In other words, the electron can flip its spin and remain in an S state.

Comment: Isn't there also a quadropole interaction?

Comment: @garyp I think (p.A)^2 contains a quadrupole term

Comment: I"m not certain, but $p$ is the dipole operator, and if I recall correctly, the quadrupole interaction involves a field gradient.  Someone reading this will know the answer for sure.

Comment: By p I mean the momentum operator.

Comment: Of course.   I'll keep quiet now.

Comment: No, it's fine. I'm no expert either, so it's good you're asking.

Comment: @garyp, this link (https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qm/Quantum/node87.html#e8.196) is useful for reviewing selection rules.

Comment: what about $({\bf d}\cdot{\bf E})$?

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov That one is definitely a dipole interaction, and the transition is forbidden (to first order, at least.).

Comment: $d \cdot E$ Hamiltonian is just a unitary transformation + dipole approximation or slowly varying field approximation applied to $p \cdot A$ , which is more fundamental. This is explained in the book "Atom-Photon Interaction" by Cohen-Tannoudji.